# Как изменить бэкграунд разделов в Menu

Tags: android-sdk, android, activity

Меню отображается в AppBarLayout, создаётся в методе :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Вопрос: Как изменить цвет бэкграунда, созданных разделов?

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще кастомную вьюшку добавить.

```
MenuItem menuItem = item.setActionView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24491108/3212712) это можно сделать используя темы и переопределив цвета фона и текста выпадающих списков:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Background Color styles -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu" 
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/Your_color_for_background</item> 
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Text Color styles -->
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Your_color_for_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: А программно как? И по отдельности каждый объект .

Comment: @semiromid, программно - почти невозможно. Можно попробовать вот это прикрутить http://stackoverflow.com/a/4591433/3212712 (говорят, уже не работает) или поставить селектор и программно менять state. Да и вообще - зачем оно вам?

Comment: Да, пробовал, не пашет. Думаете это лишнее? Мне просто интересно как это работает и для кастомизации. Или что Вы имеете в виду? Вы хотите сказать что лучше свой собственный ActionBar создать? Не могу понять Вас полностью.

Comment: @semiromid, лично мне ни разу не понадобилось менять программно цвет фона, всегда хватало селектора - тем паче, что это стандартное поведение и пользователь именно его ожидает. А так - да, если совсем хочется контроля, придётся, видать, в сорцы лезть и свою реализацию пилить. Но, ИМХО, оно того не стоит.

Comment: Я уже потратил кучу времени на создания собственного TabLayout, просто рыдать иногда хочется, почему они так издеваются над нами. SDK полуфабрикат какой-то. Неужели нельзя было добавить простую функцию получения ViewChild.

Comment: @semiromid, а в нём вас что не устраивает?

Comment: одним словом, стиль не устраивает. Хочется по больше анимации в пределах разумного.

Comment: @semiromid, ну... Порой приходится жертвовать хотелками в угоду времени и стабильности( Может, через n лет и выкатят нам что получше)